# Single digit displaying after entering double digit as input in java Program

Tags: java

1. In this below java code if i am entering double digit as input then i am getting value entered is single digit.I think problem is with i & num variable are of diff data types.
   2.If i am taking num as int then value entered is converted to different value.
   like i entered 20 & it took it as 50.
   Please help.

   ```
   class primenumber {
   public static void main(String args[]) 
       throws java.io.IOException{
           System.out.println("enter the number to test for prime number");
       char num;
       num=(char)System.in.read();
       System.out.println("number entered is "+num);
       boolean tarun =true;
               for(int i=2;i<=num/i;i++){
                       if(num%i==0){
                           tarun=false;
                               break;
                               }
                           }
               if(tarun)
               System.out.println(num +"  prime number");
               else
               System.out.println(num +" is not prime number ");
           }
       }
   ```

`output:-
enter the number to test for prime number
22
number entered is 2
2 is not prime number

Comment: System.in.read() only reads a single character. See Scanner.nextInt()

Comment: Btw, since you are new, you should see the `Tour` : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

```
num=(char)System.in.read();
```

You are casting the number to character? Why would you do this?

Since `num` is a... number, do this:

```
int num;
num = System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

char will only take a single character. hence 22 in char would be 2, it will skip the second piece. Try Integer.parseInt(System.in.read());

Answer (score 0):

You are casting it to a char? Try casting to a double (since you want a double ). :) Otherwise just leave it as an integer with Integer.parseInt(Console.readLine());